# Javascript enable/disable checkbox(es), what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, getelementbyid

I have a loop for my input checkboxes (see below).

```
<cfloop query="qGetCBList">
<input name="#qGetCBList.CheckBox#" type="checkbox" id="#qGetCBList.CheckBox#"onclick="CheckBoxSelect('#qGetCBList.CBNum#','#qGetCBList.CheckBox#','#qGetCBList.RecordCount#');">&nbsp;&nbsp;#qGetCBList.CBDesc# 
    <br /><br />
</cfloop>
```

and my javascript function is,

```
<script language="JavaScript">
CheckBoxSelect = function(CB,cbID,rCnt){
  var myVar_CB=CB;
  var myVar_CB_ID=cbID;
  var myVar_RCNT=rCnt;
    if(myVar_CB == 2) //"Chemical(s)........."
    {   
      for(i=1;i<=myVar_RCNT;i++){
        var myVar_CB_ID_FMT="cb"+i; //check box ID format
        if(i!=2){
          //alert(myVar_CB_ID_FMT);     
          document.getElementById("myVar_CB_ID_FMT").disabled=true;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      alert('good to go');  
    }
  }
</script>
```

what's happening here is, if the selected checkbox is 2 (which is the CBNum), then I want all other checkboxes to be disabled.

**P.S.** This is the bind page of the main page. When I un-comment my alert tag, it gives me the correct CBNums, but the disabling is not working. If it any useful I'm using CF8.

Feedbacks and/or alternate methods are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `myVar_CB_ID_FMT` is a variable and `"myVar_CB_ID_FMT"` is a string...

Comment: ok good eye thanks, but even if I use getElementById(myVar_CB_ID_FMT), it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but nope, that didn't do it either.

Answer (score 3):

I know nothing about ColdFusion but the basic JavaScript tips you can use are:

- Check the return value of `document.getElementById()`; don't assume it'll always return a node you can disable.
- Most browsers have a [built-in](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html) or [downloadable](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-es/firefox/addon/firebug/) debugger that allows you to inspect variables. Use that instead of plain alerts. E.g.:

  ```
  console.log(myVar_CB_ID_FMTT, document.getElementById(myVar_CB_ID_FMT));
  ```

Comment: They all (all the CBNums) return Null.

Comment: Print the values of `myVar_CB_ID_FMTT` and `document.getElementById(myVar_CB_ID_FMT)` using `console.log()` and check if they are correct. `myVar_CB_ID_FMTT` should contain a valid ID attribute and `document.getElementById(myVar_CB_ID_FMT)` should contain an `<input>` node. If that's correct, the error is after that. Otherwise, the error is before that. Please report back with your findings; currently, we don't have enough information to give you an exact answer.

Comment: those are some good pointers, really appreciate the feedback. Thanks much, and I just posted what caused and the solution to my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById("myVar_CB_ID_FMT")` is looking for an element called `myVar_CB_ID_FMT`. Does that element exist? No. Your variable myVar_CB_ID_FMT is not going to be evaluated as getElementById just sees it as the string "myVar_CB_ID_FMT".

Try `document.getElementById("cb"+i)`

The id in `getElementById(id)` is case sensitive so ensure that "cb"+i exists.

Comment: that is a good suggestion and you are right, thank you. However   getElementById(myVar_CB_ID_FMT) works.

Comment: answer kinda woke me up and I finally figured out what's going on.

In my loop when I trim my id value `.....id="#trim(qGetCBList.CheckBox)#"......` it works.
of course it had be something simple, stupid and my fault.

Thanks guys for support, you all rock.

Answer (score 0):

@Barry Jordan answer kinda woke me up and I was error checking along the line @Álvaro G. Vicario mentioned, I then finally figured out what's going on.

In my loop when I trim my id value `...id="#trim(qGetCBList.CheckBox)#"...` it works.
of course it had be something simple stupid and my fault.

Thanks guys for support, you all rock.